# EF holding onto old values in some cases

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

When using entity framework, when reading from some tables/views, it seems I get old data back. By this I mean that an external process has changed the data.

When running my code, I see EF build and run (using profiler) an SQL query to retrieve the data, but then the old values end up in the object.

What is more confusing to me is that this does not happen for all tables/view, but for the tables/views it does effect, it is consistent.

If I restart IIS I get the correct result, so clearly the values are being held somewhere.

What is causing this selective cacheing of data and how do I influence it?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What do you mean by "the old values end up in the object"? You are talking about restarting the IIS, which leads me to believe that you have a web app. Is this true? If so, are you testing it with Internet Explorer?

Comment: Yes for web app, testing in chrome. Restarting the IIS Express VS starts up. Old values means the values that used to be in the columns of the table.

Comment: Yeah, I was more concerned by the "object" part. Can you reproduce this when you run your app locally? Does your data actually get correctly pulled from the database? You need to see who is caching your data: the database server, the web app or the browser. Just because you see the correct query, it does not mean that you'll get the data you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal when you use same instance of `ObjectContext` to long. Make it's lifetime as short as possible. Instance per request should be fine.

Comment: I am using instance-per-request through dep injection. As I say, all the other tables/views are fine, data is being updated externally, the app responds by seeing the changes. SQL Profiler shows EF reading the data, and when I run the EF SQL myself it brings back the right values (the now changed values), it's just that by the time I reach my oject, the old values are there.

Comment: Actually I think I see what you are getting at. The fact that the app starts with the correct value which then never changes until I force the application to restart must mean that the instance per request is not intact for these requests.

Comment: "SQL Profiler shows EF reading the data, and when I run the EF SQL myself it brings back the right values (the now changed values)" FYI: it does not mean that cached entities are updated(sorry but this is how context works...)